# In java, is there a way to search for a specific field of a class stored in a linked list?

Tags: java, string, search, linked-list, field

I wrote a class that is to be stored in a linkedlist, with 3 fields in the class. One of these fields is a String, which I would like to search for in the linked list.

Example

```
LinkedList
      Obj1
          String name = "first";
          int age = 2;
          int size = 4;
      Obj2
          String name = "second";
          int age = 3;
          int size = 6;
      Obj3
          String name = "third";
          int age = 5;
          int size = 8;
```

If this is the linkedlist storing these three objects with the given fields, is there a way to search the linked list for the object with the name "second"?

Comment: Its part of a project I am working on, but I did try change a good majority of the code to make it more generic rather than focused on my single problem I encountered.

Comment: Just making sure, since it would be a disservice to provide detailed code samples when the question is related to homework. I've given an alternate answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for an item in the list by iteration

```
// Iterate over each object within the list
for(YourClass obj : yourLinkedList) {

    // Check if the object's name matches the criteria, in this case, the name
    // of the object has to match "second"
    if (obj.name.equals("second")) {

        // If we are within this block, it means that we found the object that has
        // its name set as "second".
        return obj;
    }
}
```

You could also make a method to make things more elegant

```
public YourClass findByName(String name) {
    for(YourClass obj : yourLinkedList) {
        if (obj.name.equals(name)) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And use it the following way

```
YourClass object = findByName("second");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [java.util.Comprator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.  You can write a method that iterates over a List and uses a comparator to find the one you are after.

Something like (not compiled):

```
for(final T value : list)
{
    if(comparator.compare(value, desired) == 0)
    {
        // match
    }
}
```

In your comparator you have it perform whatever comparison you want.

Here is a working example:

```
public class JavaApplication4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final List<Data> list;
        final List<Data> a;
        final List<Data> b;

        list = new ArrayList<Data>();
        list.add(new Data("Foo", 1));
        list.add(new Data("Bar", 10));
        list.add(new Data("Car", 10));

        a = find(list, 
                 new Data("Bar", 0),
                 new Comparator<Data>()
                 {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(final Data o1, 
                                       final Data o2) 
                    { 
                        return (o1.name.compareTo(o2.name));
                    }                  
                 });

        b = find(list, 
                 new Data(null, 10),
                 new Comparator<Data>()
                 {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(final Data o1, 
                                       final Data o2) 
                    { 
                        return (o1.count - o2.count);
                    }                  
                 });

        System.out.println(a.size());
        System.out.println(b.size());
    }

    private static List<Data> find(final List<Data>       list,
                                   final Data             desired,
                                   final Comparator<Data> comprator)
    {
        final List<Data> results;

        results = new ArrayList(list.size());

        for(final Data data : list)
        {
            if(comprator.compare(desired, data) == 0)
            {
                results.add(data);
            }
        }

        return (results);
    }

    private static class Data
    {
        private final String name;
        private final int count;

        Data(final String nm,
             final int    c)
        {
            name  = nm;
            count = c;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a generic version of the `find` method.  Using this method you would never have to write the find method again, using a method that embeds the logic for matching in the iteration code means that you would have to re-write the iteration logic for each new set of matching logic.

```
private static <T> List<T> find(final List<T>       list,
                                final T             desired,
                                final Comparator<T> comprator)
{
    final List<T> results;

    results = new ArrayList(list.size());

    for(final T value : list)
    {
        if(comprator.compare(desired, value) == 0)
        {
            results.add(value);
        }
    }

    return (results);
}
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of that will do what he wants is OGNL :-P And I think it's a safe bet he don't want to go that far!!

Comment: @Thihara - What's wrong with iterating over the list and comparing a given value to a specific field in each element??

Comment: It is flexible.  It will work for the original question, and much more

Comment: @jahroy nothing is wrong with doing that, this just gives you the ability to do that and more.  What is wrong with an easy way to do more?

Comment: I already wrote a compareTo method in the class being stored, however I thought that would be used to compare 2 instances of the class. I am trying to search for a field IN the class being stored, not compare two instances OF the class. I was playing around trying to utilize the compareTo method to search for the field, but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: Nothing says, or implies, that a Comparator has to compare the entire object.  It is written the way it is to allow that sort of flexibility.  One advantage is that when you want to write another git of code that compares two fields you do not have to write the same loop again, you just write a new Comparator.

Comment: @trawww - You're talking about implementing _compareTo_.  TofuBeer is recommending implementing a _Comparator_, which is different.  The _compareTo_ method compares two instances based on their "_natural order_" and should be used to determine ordering and/or equality.  You can define as many _Comparators_ as you want to perform different kinds of comparisons on a given object.  So... For example, you could create 3 different _Comparators_ that all compare different fields: name, age, size.

Comment: @TofuBeer - My comment: "_what is wrong with..._" was directed at Thihari.  I have understood your intention from the beginning (even though I attempted to split hairs originally).

Comment: @jahroy I assumed correctly or incorrectly that OP was inquiring about something without looping through and checking everything. Nothings wrong with iterating over it.

Comment: Using a Comparator allows you to use better search algorithms than linear search, however since this list is unsorted, comparing the values has no effect other than measuring equality.

Comment: @BenBarkay I am using it for flexibility, not speed.  The way I did it the iteration code only has to be written once regardless of the number of ways you want to search.

Comment: @TofuBeer, I fail to understand how a Comparator implementation improves flexibility over a simple iteration in his use case. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: If you want to sort by a different field, and you code the sort in to the iteration code, then you need to write the same iteration code again.  However, if you sue the method I used (and I'll update the code once more with this) you can make the iteration code generic and never have to write it again.  That would be more flexible.

Comment: @TofuBeer You can wrap iterations within methods. What I can see value from would be perhaps chaining .filter for his case. I think you should include a demonstration so that it is more understandable to others (your example with `find(List,T,Comparator<T>)` could be achieved by simply wrapping the iteration in terms of flexibility)

Comment: @BenBarkay you still have the proliferation of the same loop.  I would do the same thing you did in your answer, make a findByName method that takes the name.  The difference is that my code would have that method call the generic find method instead of rewriting the same basic loop all over again.  The nice thing about my way is that it would be pretty easy, I think, to leverage the upcoming Predicate interface in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to implement a Comparator (just in case it helps).

I find it's easier to understand if you implement the Comparator explicitly:

```
class PersonAgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person person2) {
        return p1.getAge().compareTo(p2.getAge());
    }
}
```

You might use the above like this:

```
Comparator ageComparator = new PersonAgeComparator();
List<Person> personList = // populate list somehow
Person fourYearOld = new Person();
fourYearOld.setAge(4);
for (Person p : personList) {
    if (ageComparator.compare(fourYearOld, p) == 0) {
        System.out.println(p.getName() + " is 4 years old");
    }
}
```

This doesn't make much sense for this simple example.

It would be ideal if you had several complicated ways to compare people (by height, by adjusted income, by how many states they've lived in, etc...).

Comment: That's what I wanted to express. Using a Comparator for his uses gains nothing but overcomplexity and clutter. Comparators are there in order to generalize comparison, but his need is too specific to justify an implementation. +1

Comment: @BenBarkay You assume that the code will always sort on a single field forever.  What happens when it doesn't?  What happens when the code has to sort 5 different ways?  If the original poster blindly follows the way of iterating and embedding the matching code in the for loop the code will be littered with copy/pasted for loops.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to of course, iterate through each element in the collection, checking if it matched your filter condition, and selecting the matches found. However this gets tedious the more times you need to do it, and the more complex your filter condition is. I would recommend utilizing pre-existing libraries to get the task done efficiently. Here is an example using [Google-Collections](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/):

```
final List<SomeObj> listObjs = Arrays.asList(
        new SomeObj("first", 2, 4), new SomeObj("second", 3, 6),
        new SomeObj("third", 5, 8));

final Iterable<SomeObj> filtered = Iterables.filter(listObjs,
        new Predicate<SomeObj>() {

            @Override
            public boolean apply(final SomeObj obj) {
                return "second".equals(obj.getName());
            }
        });

for (final SomeObj obj : filtered) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

The code shown would select all objects in the list with a name property of "second". Obviously, the predicate doesn't have to be an anonymous inner class - if you needed to reuse it you would just break it out to a standalone class.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through it and get it done or there's another way.

You need to override the equals method in your class (and the hashcode method as well).

After you override the equals to your desire, in this case to compare the names, create a new object with the same name and call the remove(Object o) method of the LinkedList and get the object.

You should note that with this approach you objects equality will be defined by name and that the entry will be removed from the LinkedList

Comment: Which is why I said that his object equality will then be defined by it. If you have a way to find it with just one method call you are welcome to post it.

Comment: Sorry I meant one method call :-P

Comment: Ok I'm gonna assume you aren't dumb enough to not understand what I mean :-P And say bugger off...